# Dog afraid of water bodies (not water / bathing)

Tags: dogs, training

My 1 year old mongrel is perfectly fine with water and getting baths, etc.

However, he is terrified of water bodies like lakes, the ocean, etc.

For example, I recently took him to a lake and he was very concerned and kept barking at a guy who seemed to disappear into the water and then his head appears back up. A very strange phenomenon to him I imagine. So I think it is just fear of the unknown.

As of now, he runs and plays on the (sea) beach (on a very long leash) but stays a couple meters away from the water itself. If I take him closer to the water he pulls away. If the waves touch him he runs off.

On the lake shore I can have him sit right next to the water with some treats (even without) but I think he's very **wary** of the whole situation.

Luring him into the water with a treat or toy has no effect at all. If I throw a bone or toy into very shallow (couple inches) water, he'll give it up and move back inland.

I just want him to be more comfortable around water bodies and maybe get in the water. I don't need him to go out swimming in the lake or ocean.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want the dog to go swimming in the lake? Or stop barking at strangers swimming? As you already noted, the barking was probably just a reaction to an unknown phenomenon he cannot understand, no real fear of the lake.

Comment: What have you tried to make him less afraid of those bodies of water?

Comment: @Elmy I just updated the question. I want him to be more comfortable around the water.

Comment: @SerenaT I have tried sitting right next to the water. Luring him into the water with a treat or toy has no effect at all.